# Replace all strings in dom element

Tags: jquery

I want to replace all '20' inside the id="olderpost" with '30'

I did the following:

```
<div id="olderpost"><a onclick="$.ajax({ dataType: 'script', url: '/actions/olderpost/20'}); return false;" href="/actions/olderpost/20">View older actions</a></div>

$('#olderpost').html().replace('20', '30');
```

but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace` doesn't mutate the string. Try this:

```
$('#olderpost').html($('#olderpost').html().replace(/20/g, '30'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is redundant - you have the same URL twice in the code. In order to remove this redundancy, I propose this initial state:

HTML:

```
<div id="olderpost">
    <a href="/actions/olderpost/20">View older actions</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#olderpost a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({dataType: 'script', url: $(this).attr('href')});
});
```

So, the URL is stored in the `href` attribute of the anchor. Then, if JavaScript is enabled, the click handler will make an Ajax request and the URL for that request will be taken from that same `href` attribute.

In order to replace the URL, just modify the `href` attribute of the anchor:

```
$('#olderpost a').attr('href', function(i, v) {
    return v.replace('20', '30');
});
```